# How to swap the place of given index numbers in arrays (javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am having trouble with an excercise I have from school.

We have to swap two numbers in an array given two indexes. [Here are the test cases.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWHrJ.png)

Here is my code:

```
function swap(xs, i, j) {
    var copyxs = xs.slice(0);
    for (var a = 0; a < xs.length - 1; a++) {
        if (xs.indexOf(copyxs[a]) == i) {
            xs[a] = copyxs[j];
        }
        if (xs.indexOf(copyxs[a]) == j) {
            xs[a] = copyxs[i];
        }
    }
    return xs;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have the indexes of the array that needs to be swapped, **you don't have to slice and loop through the array elements** to do that. 
Just **keep one of the index values in a temp variable and re-assign the values** as shown below :

```js
function swap (xs, i, j){
  var temp = xs[j];
  xs[j] = xs[i];
  xs[i] = temp;
  return xs;
}


console.log(swap([1,2,3], 0, 1))
```

Comment: Oh yes thank you, way better method! But I still don't understand why my method doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

No need to `slice` array, you can just reassign the values at the given indices:

```
function swap(arr, i, j) {
  var temp = arr[i]; //temporarily store original value at i position
  arr[i] = arr[j]; //reassign value at i position to be value at j position
  arr[j] = temp; //reassign value at j position to original value at i position
  return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case your teacher doesn't need you to modify input array you could do this with a map.

```js
var input = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
    var swap = (xs, i, j) => xs.map((x,index,arr) => {
      if (index === i) return arr[j];
      if (index === j) return arr[i];
      return x;
    });
    console.log(swap(input, 2, 4));
```

Or in a old function :

```js
var input = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
    function swap(xs, i, j) {
      return xs.map((x,index,arr) => {
        if (index === i) return arr[j];
        if (index === j) return arr[i];
        return x;
      });
    }
    console.log(swap(input, 2, 4));
```